# Import CSV, summarize and display result in HTML e-mail body

Tags: powershell

I am trying to send a HTML report in PowerShell by e-mail but instead of username and count as the results I receive this as the body of the e-mail:

```
ClassId2e4f51ef21dd47e99d3c952918aff9cd pageHeaderEntry pageFooterEntry autosizeInfo    shapeInfo   groupingEntry
033ecb2bc07a4d43b5ef94ed5a35d280                Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.TableHeaderInfo   
9e210fe47d09416682b841769c78b8a3                    
27c87ef9bbda4f709f6b4002fa4af63c                    
27c87ef9bbda4f709f6b4002fa4af63c                    
27c87ef9bbda4f709f6b4002fa4af63c                    
27c87ef9bbda4f709f6b4002fa4af63c                    
27c87ef9bbda4f709f6b4002fa4af63c                    
27c87ef9bbda4f709f6b4002fa4af63c                    
4ec4f0187cb04f4cb6973460dfe252df                    
cf522b78d86c486691226b40aa69e95c
```

what am I doing wrong?

this is how I am trying to do it: import the CSV, Group by user and e-mail

```
$list = Import-Csv -Path $csvfile -Delimiter ","
$pivot = ($list | Group-Object -Property User -NoElement | Where-Object {$_.Name -ne ""} | Select-Object Name,Count | Format-Table)
$out = $pivot | ConvertTo-Html | Out-String
Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer $smtpServer -To $to -From $from -Subject $subject -Body $out -BodyAsHtml -Attachments $csvfile -WarningAction:SilentlyContinue
```

Comment: Remove the `Format-Table` and `Out-String`.

Comment: I don't think `Out-String` is hurting anything here, but to reiterate Olaf's comment, you should never be capturing the output of a `Format-XXXXX` cmdlet. Things like `Format-Table` and `Format-List` are designed to format output for display, specifically for the console, and the data they generate is not intended for re-use.

Comment: Thank you both, indeed the removal of "| Format-Table" did the trick.